# Clojure-lsp in vim - outdated message box doesn't go away?

Tags: neovim, plugin-coc, filetype-clojure

I recently added the coc extension for clojure. When I opened Vim it asked me to install clojure-lsp from Github. I did that.

Now, every time I open my nvim with a clojure file I get a warning to update clojure-lsp.

When I click yes, it does nothing. The message continues every time I open a clojure file.

[image]

Comment: It's fine to ask this question here, but I think this is the sort of question where you'll probably get better results by asking on the plugin's issue tracker; it's possibly a bug, and if not, the author(s) are much more familiar with how it works than anyone here.

Comment: Fair point. Understood. Thank you @MartinTournoij